# Memory Friendly Python Dict Key Management

Tags: python, dictionary, memory-management

I am getting a `Memory Error` in a dictionary update of the following:

```
for x in depot:
    if x in self.xx:
        self.xx[x] += 1
    else:
        self.xx[x] = 1
```

And it is giving me the error at `self.xx[x] = 1` line.
 
I assume there is a reinitialization going on behind...

How can I solve this issue in a memory friendly way, without using database like structures?
Currently I am working on a `Trie structure`, is it for nothing or do you think it can help me?

Comment: How do you call this loop? Can you show a minimal example of your class and how it is used?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the real culprit for the memory error is the code snippet you provided. We need more context.

Comment: Hey, @uhuuyouneverknow did you find any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem must come from the size of your depot (which I assume is a list). You try to iterate through all of it and for every iteration you check the **entire** `self.xx` dictionary if it contains `x` which probably causes your memory error.

You can try to work around this by using the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from collections which is optimized:

```
from collections import Counter

self.xx = Counter(depot)
```

Now the `self.xx` is a dictionary with each key being a distinct value from depot and it's corresponding value being the sum of occurrences in depot

For example:

```
depot = ["x", "c", "b", "x", "c", "c", "x", "b", "x", "x", "c", "x", "b"]
self.xx = Counter(depot)
for item in self.xx:
    print("{}: {}".format(item, self.xx[item]))
```

will print:

```
b: 3
x: 6
c: 4
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) in `self.xx`?

Your code would look a bit like this:

```
self.xx = defaultdict(int)
for x in depot:
    self.xx[x] += 1
```

Comment: Not sure this fixes anything relating to the original problem in the OP

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: He asked for something that manages memory better, and his original code is re-implementing the behaviour from defaultdict. If the error is really coming from one of the lines in the original code, using this will solve it.